# My Tkinter exe App realized can't find my module

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, pyinstaller, exe

i create an app in Python with Tkinter. When I execute this code with Pycharm it works, but after creating the exe i get this error. [I load the error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNrVo.png)
I used pyinstaller to create the exe: `pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon=icona_interfaccia.ico v2_tkinter_robot_gui.py` 
The app code is divided into four folders, called:

- Vision_Code
- Interface_Code
- Manual_movements_Code (Codice_Manuale)
- Kinematics_Code (Codice_Cinematica)

All this four folder are saved in one call Code.

The `v2_tkinter_robot_gui.py` is the main file, where all the codes I wrote converge and it is saved in the folder called Interface_Code.

To import my modules I use the following wording:

```
from Codice_Manuale.Movimentazione_manuale import moveJabs, moveJ
#from Codice_Cinematica.cinematica_pallettizzatore import *
#from Codice_Manuale.funzioni_gestione_meccanica import aggiusta_zeri, workspace, 
finecorsa_angoli, home_braccio
from Codice_Visione.movimento_ciclo_completo_visione import *
from Codice_Visione.movimento_immediato_visione import *
```

I had already created an exe on another machine that I no longer have. On this one it worked without problems.

Thanks in advance for the help